# Not generating a <ProjectName>-Addin.dna file

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I want to use open-source excel-dna.addin package
But on very start, I noticed that my file -Addin.dna is not created, because Im using .net6-windows TargetFramework

It works fine when Im using .net framework 4.8

I can see that builds that file in my bin/debug folder, but I really need persistent file to put some xml code for ribbon.

What would be an a pproach for excel.dna in .net6 environment?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you return the ribbon xml directly from an override in the Ribbon controller class's `GetCustomUI`.
Alternatively, you can create an xml file that you embed as a resource in the C# project, and extract at runtime using the `ResourceManager`, to return it from `GetCustomUI`.